# Hover event returning multiple values instead of those pertaining to hover target

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I have had a browse through issues I felt might be relevant and help me but I'm still having a problem, so hopefully someone can help. This is the part of a word game that shows a valid word on a grid in the direction of the arrow you hover over. There can be a single word (and thus a single direction arrow) per turn or multiple arrows at different positions (herein lies my problem).

The problem is in the jquery.hover(), it is printing the expected id and index but printing all the various states of horiz.

```
function placeIndicators(index) {
var board = readBoard(),
    id;

clearBoard(board);

if (suggestions.length > index) {
    var suggestion = suggestions[index];

    for (var i = 0; i < suggestion.positions.length; i++) {
        (function (suggestion, i) {

            // example contents of pos  {horiz: true, startPos: 5, word: 'blinky', score: 20}  
            var pos = suggestion.positions[i],
                rowOrCol = pos.rowOrCol,
                startPos = pos.start;

            var horiz = pos.horiz;

            if (pos.horiz) {
                id = '#s' + rowOrCol + '_' + startPos;
                $(id).addClass('arrow side-arrow');
            } else {
                id = '#s' + startPos + '_' + rowOrCol;
                $(id).addClass('arrow down-arrow');
            }
            $(id).attr('placeholder', '*');

            $('.arrow').hover(function () {
                console.log('id: ' + this.id + ' Index: ' + index + ' horiz: ' + horiz);
                showSuggestion(index, extractIndex(id, horiz));
            }, function () {
                console.log(index);
                clearBoard(board);
                placeIndicators(index);
            });
        })(suggestion, i);
    }
}
```

}

I would just like it to print only the details pertaining to the particular cell I am hovering over, not all the contents of the array. Works fine if suggestion.positions.length == 1.

Example output when hovering over a cell when suggestion.positions.length > 1:

> id: s6_7 Index: 4 horiz: true 
>   id: s6_7 Index: 4 horiz: false 
>   id: s6_7 Index: 4 horiz: true

Many thanks.

Comment: I'd just like to point out your `console.log()` is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the HTML I was not able to debug this in jsfiddle. However, since you are binding event inside the loop, it might be possible that the event hover is attached to .arrow multiple times. So when you hover over the element, hover triggers multiple times causing this error.

Due to the property of closure, horiz is preserved in the hover event handler and prints different values based on the state of horiz when arrow event handler was attached.

A possible solution is to move $('.arrow').hover outside the loop. But the variable horiz wont be available. For this I can suggest using another attribute for storing horiz in HTML

```
function placeIndicators(index) {
  var board = readBoard(),
    id;

  clearBoard(board);

  if (suggestions.length > index) {
  var suggestion = suggestions[index];

  for (var i = 0; i < suggestion.positions.length; i++) {
      (function (suggestion, i) {

        // example contents of pos  {horiz: true, startPos: 5, word: 'blinky', score: 20}  
        var pos = suggestion.positions[i],
            rowOrCol = pos.rowOrCol,
            startPos = pos.start;

        var horiz = pos.horiz;

        if (pos.horiz) {
            id = '#s' + rowOrCol + '_' + startPos;
            $(id).addClass('arrow side-arrow');
        } else {
            id = '#s' + startPos + '_' + rowOrCol;
            $(id).addClass('arrow down-arrow');
        }
        $(id).attr('placeholder', '*');
        $(id).attr('data-horiz', horiz);
    })(suggestion, i);
  }
  $('.arrow').hover(function () {
       var horiz = $(this).attr('data-horiz');
       console.log('id: ' + this.id + ' Index: ' + index + ' horiz: ' + horiz);
       showSuggestion(index, extractIndex(id, horiz));
    }, function () {
       console.log(index);
       clearBoard(board);
       placeIndicators(index);
  });
}
```